# takePicture method not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, face-detection, imagepicker, flutter-image-picker

Creating an application for face detection. using camera plugin to capture picture. Below is the code to capture image on clicking button.
I want to capture image and convert it into InputImage format. And do the navigation. Code for converting is not working.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await controller!.takePicture().then((value) async {
            // Convert the image to a file
            final File _capimg = File(value.path);
            final bytes = await _capimg.readAsBytes();
            final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
            final path = '${directory.path}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg';
            final file = File(path);
            await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

            print('The captured image path is: ${_capimg.path}');

            setState(() {
              _imageFile = _capimg;
              _imagePath = path;
            });
            final File convimg = File('path/to/image.jpg');
            if (!convimg.existsSync()) {
              convimg.createSync();
            }
            // Convert the file to InputImage
            final inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(_imagePath);
            print('The input image is: ${inputImage.metadata?.size}');

            processCameraImage(inputImage);
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Capture',
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
```

Below is the processCameraImage method.

```
Future<void> processCameraImage( InputImage inputImage) async {
    if (_isCameraReady && !_detectingFaces) {
      try {
        setState(() {
          _detectingFaces = true;
        });
        final faces = await _faceDetector.processImage(_inputImage);
        if (faces.isNotEmpty) {
          setState(() {
            _faces = faces;
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      } finally {
        setState(() {
          _detectingFaces = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the log: -

```
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on RMX3231 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9100?uri=http://127.0.0.1:61941/hYEWHKXbVS4=/
W/Camera  (25390): The selected imageFormatGroup is not supported by Android. Defaulting to yuv420
I/Camera  (25390): startPreview
D/IMGGralloc(25390): InsertBlankEntry: SPRD_DATA_SPACE ui64Stamp:2486938,eYUVColorSpace:2, yuv_info:2
D/IMGGralloc(25390): Gralloc Register  w:1280, h:720, f:0x22, usage:0x20000106, ui64Stamp:2486938, sSize:1384448, line = 2335
D/IMGGralloc(25390): InsertBlankEntry: SPRD_DATA_SPACE ui64Stamp:2486942,eYUVColorSpace:2, yuv_info:2
D/IMGGralloc(25390): Gralloc Register  w:1280, h:720, f:0x22, usage:0x20000106, ui64Stamp:2486942, sSize:1384448, line = 2335
D/IMGGralloc(25390): InsertBlankEntry: SPRD_DATA_SPACE ui64Stamp:2486947,eYUVColorSpace:2, yuv_info:2
D/IMGGralloc(25390): Gralloc Register  w:1280, h:720, f:0x22, usage:0x20000106, ui64Stamp:2486947, sSize:1384448, line = 2335
D/ProfileInstaller(25390): Installing profile for com.example.flutterapp.facerecognition
D/IMGGralloc(25390): InsertBlankEntry: SPRD_DATA_SPACE ui64Stamp:2486955,eYUVColorSpace:2, yuv_info:2
D/IMGGralloc(25390): Gralloc Register  w:1280, h:720, f:0x22, usage:0x20000106, ui64Stamp:2486955, sSize:1384448, line = 2335
D/IMGGralloc(25390): Gralloc Register  w:720, h:1512, f:0x1, usage:0xb00, ui64Stamp:2486959, sSize:4378624, line = 2335
D/IMGGralloc(25390): Gralloc Register  w:720, h:1512, f:0x1, usage:0xb00, ui64Stamp:2486963, sSize:4378624, line = 2335
I/Camera  (25390): runPrecaptureSequence
I/Camera  (25390): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
D/CameraCaptureCallback(25390): CameraCaptureCallback | state: STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE_START | afState: 2 | aeState: 2
D/CameraCaptureCallback(25390): CameraCaptureCallback | state: STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE_DONE | afState: 2 | aeState: 2
I/Camera  (25390): captureStillPicture                               
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: ExposureLockFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: ExposurePointFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: ZoomLevelFeature     
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: AutoFocusFeature     
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: NoiseReductionFeature
I/Camera  (25390): updateNoiseReduction | currentSetting: fast         
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: FocusPointFeature    
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: ResolutionFeature    
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: SensorOrientationFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: FlashFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: ExposureOffsetFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: FpsRangeFeature
I/Camera  (25390): sending capture request
D/CameraCaptureCallback(25390): CameraCaptureCallback | state: STATE_CAPTURING | afState: 2 | aeState: 2
D/IMGGralloc(25390): Gralloc Register  w:1596606, h:1, f:0x21, usage:0x6, ui64Stamp:2486996, sSize:1597440, line = 2335
D/CameraCaptureCallback(25390): CameraCaptureCallback | state: STATE_CAPTURING | afState: 2 | aeState: 2
D/CameraCaptureCallback(25390): CameraCaptureCallback | state: STATE_CAPTURING | afState: 2 | aeState: 2
I/Camera  (25390): onImageAvailable
I/Camera  (25390): unlockAutoFocus
I/Camera  (25390): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
I/flutter (25390): The captured image path is: /data/user/0/com.example.flutterapp.facerecognition/cache/CAP4679855200037562703.jpg
E/flutter (25390): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PathNotFoundException: Cannot create file, path = 'path/to/image.jpg' 
(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
E/flutter (25390): #0      _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:675:7)
E/flutter (25390): #1      _File.createSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:306:5)
E/flutter (25390): #2      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:facerecognition/main.dart:142:23)
E/flutter (25390): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25390): #3      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:facerecognition/main.dart:125:11)
E/flutter (25390): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25390):
I/facerecognitio(25390): Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 84019(2578KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3386KB/6773KB, paused 180us total 71
.663ms
I/Camera  (25390): runPrecaptureSequence
I/Camera  (25390): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
D/CameraCaptureCallback(25390): CameraCaptureCallback | state: STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE_START | afState: 2 | aeState: 2
D/CameraCaptureCallback(25390): CameraCaptureCallback | state: STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE_DONE | afState: 2 | aeState: 2
I/Camera  (25390): captureStillPicture
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: ExposureLockFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: ExposurePointFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: ZoomLevelFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: AutoFocusFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: NoiseReductionFeature
I/Camera  (25390): updateNoiseReduction | currentSetting: fast
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: FocusPointFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: ResolutionFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: SensorOrientationFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: FlashFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: ExposureOffsetFeature
D/Camera  (25390): Updating builder with feature: FpsRangeFeature
I/Camera  (25390): sending capture request
D/CameraCaptureCallback(25390): CameraCaptureCallback | state: STATE_CAPTURING | afState: 2 | aeState: 2
D/CameraCaptureCallback(25390): CameraCaptureCallback | state: STATE_CAPTURING | afState: 2 | aeState: 2
D/CameraCaptureCallback(25390): CameraCaptureCallback | state: STATE_CAPTURING | afState: 2 | aeState: 2
D/CameraCaptureCallback(25390): CameraCaptureCallback | state: STATE_CAPTURING | afState: 2 | aeState: 2
I/Camera  (25390): onImageAvailable
I/Camera  (25390): unlockAutoFocus
I/Camera  (25390): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
I/flutter (25390): The captured image path is: /data/user/0/com.example.flutterapp.facerecognition/cache/CAP8634855078985179270.jpg
E/flutter (25390): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PathNotFoundException: Cannot create file, path = 'path/to/image.jpg' 
(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
E/flutter (25390): #0      _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:675:7)
E/flutter (25390): #1      _File.createSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:306:5)
E/flutter (25390): #2      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:facerecognition/main.dart:142:23)
E/flutter (25390): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25390): #3      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:facerecognition/main.dart:125:11)
E/flutter (25390): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25390):
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says "Cannot create file, path = 'path/to/image.jpg'"

You literally have "path/to/image.jpg" in your code.

```
final File convimg = File('path/to/image.jpg');
```

Change it to point to a file in your temporary directory or somewhere else you have write access.

```
final File convimg = File('${directory.path}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}-converted.jpg');
```

Comment: Hi!  where can i find the captured image in my device. and also this is what i get in console .
I/flutter (31979): The target directory is: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.flutterapp.facerecognition/files/Download
I/flutter (31979): Image file exists at path: File: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.flutterapp.facerecognition/files/1692945977744-converted.jpg'    
I/flutter (31979): The captured image path is: /data/user/0/com.example.flutterapp.facerecognition/cache/CAP1085318684185533338.jpg
I/flutter (31979): The input image is: null

Answer (score 0):

On your error log there is two line shows

```
I/flutter (25390): The captured image path is:/data/user/0/com.example.flutterapp.facerecognition/cache/CAP4679855200037562703.jpg
E/flutter (25390): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled 
Exception: PathNotFoundException: Cannot create file, path = 'path/to/image.jpg'
```

You need to change on below line
`final File convimg = File('path/to/image.jpg');`

Use [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package, which provides root and app files directory for both "external storage" (internal flash) and SD card (if present), as well as available space for each storage to get the correct file path.